# How to deal with the repeated jar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, jar

As shown in the figure,"xxx finished with non-zero exit value 2",some people say that is the repeated jars caused it.But I did not find the repeat jars yet.So,how can I deal with it?

http://i3.tietuku.com/10ec1b3775cbb850.png

App - build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myatejx.quicknote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
    compile project(':Ldrawer')
    compile project(':Snackbar')
}
```

SwipeMenuListView - Library - build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Snackbar - Library - build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
}

apply from: 'maven-push.gradle'
```

Ldrawer - Library - build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}

//apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: Rather than importing the `support-v4 jar`, try replacing it with `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'` instead. I am not very sure but you might want to check your methods count by using [dex-count ](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) plugin. Sometimes, it might be the case too.

Comment: Thanks,and I have replaced the suppot-v4 to com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0 as you say.But it still doesn't work.I just want to know,how can I deal with the "finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Comment: In fact,I don't know what means when people say"jars repeated".If it means different modules in the same project use the different version of support v4.jar,keep the versions coincident can be help?If it means modules in the same project can not repeat to import the support v4,so how a module call the v4 from another module?@YeLinAung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
In your code

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myatejx.quicknote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

If multidex is enabled.The gradle will neglect the duplicate dex files

Comment: Compile failed while the support v4 of Ldrawer was delete,and unfortunately,it caused a new problem and I have no idea how deal with it too...    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/TimeUtils.class

Comment: ok do you tried the 1st method that is adding  "multiDexEnabled true".
The "multiDexEnabled true" is working for me.

Comment: Yes, and thanks a lot ! After re-import the jars and it works :)