# issue Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, executable-jar

I make one project like below structure

[image]

**my build.gradel file as below**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pkg.com.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
/*compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])*/
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
 }
```

I tried all possibility as per current accepted answer like below

**1. Comment dependency lib line form build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
/*compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])*/
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
 }
```

but if i remove this than in my class file getting error like your library is missing for this class

**2. By making change line as compile to provided**

when i making above change than my application not run and give message like like null pointer due to library not getting to respective class.

So i m getting confuse which way i follow for this any idea how can i solve this problem? your all suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Ganesh Kumar :See this link my error logcat [http://pastie.org/10313901](http://pastie.org/10313901)

Comment: any external jar u r using?

Comment: You may find answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509538/gradle-failed-to-build-with-error-multiple-dex-files-define.

Comment: N5 : yes many more see above image in my question i used that no of jars

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199135/how-to-deal-with-the-repeated-jar-in-android-studio/31199486#31199486

Comment: Try to use gradle instead of jar files.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284984/2591002) also

Answer (score 0):

In defaultConfig add :

```
multiDexEnabled = true
```

And in same build.gradle add :

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

And in dependencies add :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}
```

Comment: Android Weblineindia : Hi Thanks....After adding multiDexEnabled = true resolve multiDex exception but at loading time many class file not generate so its throw error classDefNotFound. how can i resolve this?

Comment: While i am adding this dependency its at run time throw exception classDefNotfoun                                                                                 `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'`
`compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'`
 `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'`
 `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'`
 `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`